# Accessmode in PVC and pod

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

I have a pvc with accessmode `ReadOnlyMany`. I created a pod which uses the above pvc and found that I can write to the mounted path. Is this expected behaviour or something to do with the volume plugin that I am using.

Comment: check if whatever you wrote to the mounted path is persistent or not? also please post your yaml files here.

Comment: yes. It is persistent.

Comment: Without yaml files, it will be hard to determine the issue. My assumption is that you need to specify readOnly: true on the Pod specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information is hard to say what it is.

The most common mistakes are:

1) Like @vaqars mentioned in comment it could be lack of `readOnly:true` element in pod/deployment manifest.

```
volumes:
- name: <volumeName>
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: <claimName>
    readOnly: true
```

2) Your **PersistentVolume** and **PersistentVolumeClaim** does not have `accessMode: ReadOnlyMany`.

3) Your Volume Plugin might not support `ReadOnlyMany`. Please check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#volume-mode) if your Volume Plugin supports this access mode.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `accessMode` on a `pvc` to `ReadOnlyMany` does not guarantee that the underlying `pv` will not allow writes. Even more, setting the `pv`'s `accessMode` to `ReadOnlyMany` will not guarantee that the underlying storage will reject writes. As written in the official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

> **Note:** Kubernetes uses volume access modes to match PersistentVolumeClaims and PersistentVolumes. In some cases, the volume access modes also constrain where the PersistentVolume can be mounted. Volume access modes do **not** enforce write protection once the storage has been mounted. Even if the access modes are specified as ReadWriteOnce, ReadOnlyMany, or ReadWriteMany, they don't set any constraints on the volume. For example, even if a PersistentVolume is created as ReadOnlyMany, it is no guarantee that it will be read-only. If the access modes are specified as ReadWriteOncePod, the volume is constrained and can be mounted on only a single Pod.

If you would like to test this out for yourself, here is a reproduceable example modified from an example in *Chapter06* of **Kubernetes in action** (tested with `minikube version v1.30.1`, `Kubernetes version v1.26.3`):

```
└► cat mongodb-pv-hostpath.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadOnlyMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /tmp/mongodb
└► cat mongodb-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongodb-pvc
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadOnlyMany
  storageClassName: ""
└► cat mongodb-pod-pvc.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mongo
    name: mongodb
    volumeMounts:
    - name: mongodb-data
      mountPath: /data/db
    ports:
    - containerPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  volumes:
  - name: mongodb-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mongodb-pvc
```

Once you apply all of these files to the minikube cluster, you can run `k exec -it mongodb -- mongosh` and run successful commands to write to the mongoDB even though the mounted volume is set as `ReadOnlyMany`.